# How can I use a model trained with batches to make predictions with single sample?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I'm training a PyTorch model with batches of 128 images, and after going through multiple convolutions, they're flattened (with `.flatten`) before being passed to a linear layer. The input size of the linear layer accounts for the batch size, so the dimensions don't line up when I pass a single image to the trained model. How is this typically dealt with?

Answer (score 1):

Your scenario is extremely common. You generally want to train in batches and then predict on individual samples.

First, it's crucial to understand that training and using a model are separate endeavors. While you might be able to reuse code, it is in no way a requirement.

I like how [PyTorch lightning](https://lightning.ai/docs/pytorch/stable/starter/introduction.html) handles it. Essentially, they define two methods in their interfaces, `training_step` for training and `predict_step` for inference. As suggested, they deal with both aspects. And what you could always do is use the `predict_step` as part of your `training_step` to avoid duplicate code.

For your use case, I would make sure that your prediction method is flexible when it comes to batch size (so when you predict, you pass a batch of 1 item) or I would design two separate methods in case the logic between the two varies enough.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest flattening with `.flatten(start_dim=1)` instead (keep the batch dimension 128 unaffected, flatten information for each image only). **We should not have the last linear layer input size dependent on the batch dimension**. Check out this implementation of ResNet in PyTorch, see line 112 of [ResNet PyTorch Implemnetation](https://github.com/Pehlevan-Group/nn_curvature/blob/master/src/model/ResNet.py). Our model should be compatible with any input batch size.

Think about linear regression with design matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$, with $n$ samples each with $p$ dimension. We want to train a weight vector $\beta \in \mathbb{R}^p$ that should not depend on $n$.

Using `.flatten(start_dim=1)` makes the input to the linear layer a $n$ by $p$ matrix, where $n$ is the batch size 128 here, and $p$ is determined by the input dimension and convolution settings.